# Вызов функции по указателю

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Функция принимает в качестве параметра указатель на функцию-член базового класса. Как вызвать эту функцию, передавая ей нужный указатель на соответствующую функцию-член?

Пример:

```
void MyClass::func(void(*fptr)()){
   for(size_t i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
      for(size_t q=0; q<nit.size();q++){
         (items[i]->*nit[q])();
      } 
   }
}

void MyClass::fill1(){
   func(void(*fill)());
} 

void MyClass::delete1(){
   func(void(*delete)());
}
```

То, что в хедере:

```
  typedef  void (Base::*fptr)();
  std::vector<fptr> nit;
  MyClass(){
     fptr delete=&Base::delete;
     fptr fill=&Base::fill;
     nit.push_back(delete);
     nit.push_back(fill);
  }
```

Компилятор выдает следующую ошибку: invalid use of member function (did you forget the «()» ?) 
func(void(*delete)());
func(void(*fill)());

Comment: Эээ... Ваш `func` вовсе не использует переданный аргумент, это раз. А во-вторых, в определении `func` `fptr` — это не typedef-тип, а имя локальной переменной. Что должна делать функция `func` на самом деле?

Comment: @VladD Она для каждого из объектов дочерних классов, лежащих в векторе items должна вызывать соответствующую виртуальную функцию из базового класса.

Comment: Окей, это значит, что двойной цикл в `func` не нужен?

Comment: @VladD Вы правы, необходимо лишь вызывать эту функцию при передаче конкретного указателя.

Answer (score 4):

Судя по всему, нужно переписать функции так:

```
void MyClass::func(fptr f) {
   for (size_t i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
       (items[i]->*f)();
   }
}

void MyClass::fill1() {
   func(&Base::fill);
} 

void MyClass::delete1() {
   func(&Base::delete);
}
```

Впрочем, поскольку `delete` — ключевое слово, думаю, это тоже не скомпилируется, и стоит переименовать функцию `delete` во что-то другое.

Comment: Работает, огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @ascot: Не стоит благодарности, успехов в изучении языка!